# How do I update a reply to show after submission in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am still struggling to grasp the whole concept of react yet. I want to implement a Query form where user will add a reply. But from when I've done, i have to refresh the page to see the replies which a good UX. Here's my code

```
const { id } = useParams();
    
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const queryItem = Queries.find((item, indx) => indx === parseInt(id));

// ********************************************************REPLY QUERY
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);

    const params = JSON.stringify({
        id: userID
        message: queryMessage,
    });

    Axios(`${api.baseURL}/replyquery`, {
        method: "POST",
        data: params,
    })
        .then((res) => {
            setLoading(false);
            setQueryMessage("");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            setLoading(false);
        });
};
```

Below is my query render

```
<div className=" px-4">
    {queryItem?.reply?.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
            <div className="">
                <p className="">
                    <span>
                        <IoArrowRedo className="text-black" />
                    </span>
                    Replied by: {item?.replied_by?.name}
                </p>
                <p className="">{item?.reply_date}</p>
            </div>

            <p>{item?.reply_message}</p>
        </div>
    ))}
</div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use usestate to re-render. setQueryItem after res ok.

```
const [queryItem, setQueryItem] = useState(Queries.find((item, indx) => indx === parseInt(id)));
```

```
const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);

    const params = JSON.stringify({
        id: userID,
        message: queryMessage,
    });

    try {
        const res = await Axios(`${api.baseURL}/replyquery`, {
            method: "POST",
            data: params,
        });

        setLoading(false);
        setQueryMessage("");
//setQueryItem...
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setLoading(false);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to create a state to store the submitted reply.

```
const [reply, setReply] = useState("");
```

Then in your form submission function, update the reply state variable with the submitted value, something like this

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  // ... code to submit reply to server ...
  setReply("Your reply has been submitted successfully.");
}
```

And finally just call it where you want

```
{reply && <p>{reply}</p>}
```